# Chrome and Preview image viewing displays garbage

Tags: macos, opengl, driver, gpu

I know this is not a directly programming related question, but after skimming in the list of SE.com sites, I think this is my best shot of getting a decent answer.

Every once in a while, when view high definition images, they appear like uninitialised memory on the GPU. Like so:

[image]

While the [actual image is should look like this](http://www.caermersklooster.be/sites/default/files/exhibition_gallery/POV_9897-2-2474470784-O.jpg) (taken from Google image search results):

[image]

This happens in Chrome and Preview on OS X on my laptop. Now, I'm wondering what this is caused by: broken hardware? A bug in the hardware? Or just a bug in software (like the driver for the GPU or OS X itself)? I think that a bug in both Chrome and Preview is unlikely. Am I the only one experiencing this every once in a while? I believe that Chrome uses OpenGL.

For people blaming the Beta version of OS X: I had this before the beta as well.

My specs:
Intel HD Graphics 3000
MacBookPro8,1
OS X 10.11.2 Beta (15C47a)
And the `version.plist` file in the `AppleIntelHD3000Graphics.kext` kernel extension:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>BuildVersion</key>
    <string>419</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>10.0.40</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>10.0.0</string>
    <key>ProjectName</key>
    <string>GraphicsDrivers</string>
    <key>SourceVersion</key>
    <string>10000040000000</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: I had this problem when I was using an old driver for my Intel HD graphics, I updated to the latest version and haven't seen it since.

Comment: @CupofJava: I assume you were working on Windows? Because updating a GPU driver on OS X always comes through the update center of OS X itself. There are no drivers available for download on Intel's website for OS X.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux I use OS X and I have occasionally seen this problem, I think I have a fancier graphics card too.

Comment: This looks like a bug in either Chrome or your GPU drivers. As it's not a programming question, I'm voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo: True, it's off topic, and I know that. But instead of voting for close, suggest an alternative site, please.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux I don't know of one. Maybe SuperUser, but you need to check yourself. Either way, it doesn't make this any less off-topic on SO.